# Cannot send email with Graph API

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, microsoft-graph-api

Im having issues trying to send an email from Graph API,

In my startup class, I have the following:

```
services
    .AddAuthentication(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(Configuration.GetSection("AzureAd"))
    .EnableTokenAcquisitionToCallDownstreamApi(initialScopes)
    .AddMicrosoftGraph(Configuration.GetSection("DownstreamApi"))
    .AddInMemoryTokenCaches();
```

And I have a class used to controll graph access:

```
public class GraphApiService
{
    private readonly GraphServiceClient _graphServiceClient;

    // Inject Microsfot Graphi API client into GraphApiService
    public GraphApiService(GraphServiceClient graphServiceClient)
    {
        _graphServiceClient = graphServiceClient;
    }

    // Gets the Display Name of the interactive user
    public async Task<string> GetCurrentDisplayName()
    {
        var user = await _graphServiceClient.Me.Request().GetAsync();

        string displayName = user.DisplayName;
        return displayName;
    }
        // Send email from the interactive user
    public async void SendEmailFromInteractiveUser()
    {
        var message = new Message
        {
            Subject = "Meet for lunch?",
            Body = new ItemBody
            {
                ContentType = BodyType.Text,
                Content = "The new cafeteria is open."
            },
            ToRecipients = new List<Recipient>()
            {
                new Recipient
                {
                    EmailAddress = new EmailAddress
                    {
                        Address = "myemail@email.com"
                    }
                }
            }
        };

        await _graphServiceClient.Me.SendMail(message, null).Request().PostAsync();

    }
}
```

I am able to recieve the display name, name, email, etc.
Anything from the .Me

However, im trying to send an email from

```
bool saveToSent = true;
await graphServiceClient.Me.SendMail(message, saveToSent).Request().PostAsync();
```

I have all the proper permissions in azure, (user.read user.readbasic.all mail.send)

Am I missing something? I have been told to use

```
await graphServiceClient.Users[username].SendMail(message, false).Request().PostAsync();
```

But this doesnt make sense that i'm already able to pull basic user information using _graphServiceClient.Me.Request().GetAsync();

Please help.

Thanks

Comment: What is the format of the message?  Try sending an empty string in the email and see if it works.

Comment: Hi @jdweng I have added an edit to my question. I have used a basic message format taken from the in-browser graph explorer Microsoft offers

Comment: Looks like you are just sending a text message.  The email is missing credentials which has been required since Net 4.0.

Comment: @jdweng _graphServiceClient is being injected from my service collection in my startup class which already contains my credentials.
I am able to pull other user information from graph API so I know its working, but just cant send email.

Comment: SMTP is being used (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.mail.smtpclient.send?force_isolation=true&view=net-5.0) which has following : client.UseDefaultCredentials = true;  The graph client is using following : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/outlook-mail-concept-overview.  Do you have following : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/sdks/choose-authentication-providers?force_isolation=true&tabs=CS.  Do you have an outlook account on machine? Are you running from home or company network?

Comment: @jdweng I am running from a company network and yes I have an outlook email account with my company that I am trying to use.
And yes I do have the folllowing auth providers, I have set it up this way: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/scenario-web-app-call-api-app-configuration?tabs=aspnetcore#option-1-call-microsoft-graph

Comment: Link has : OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme.  Default schema is using the User Login Settings on the machine (Control Panel).  So the From address of email has to be the same account as the credentials.  Can you connect to the outlook from account on the machine you are using?

Comment: Try following to see if working : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/clients-and-mobile-in-exchange-online/authenticated-client-smtp-submission?force_isolation=true#how-do-you-know-this-worked

Comment: @jdweng I login to my computer using my upn.
domain\lastnamefirstname or lastnamefirstname@domain.com

But my email is the opposite, it is firstnamelastname@domain.com

Otherwise yes, It is the same "AD account"

Comment: The email account can have more than one alias.  If you can send from machine using outlook than the default account should be correct.  Read following : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/1x-to-2x/identity-2x?force_isolation=true&view=aspnetcore-5.0#setting-default-authentication-schemes or https://developers.onelogin.com/blog/how-to-use-openid-connect-authentication-with-dotnet-core?force_isolation=true

Comment: @jdweng I found the solution and added to my answers, thank you again for all your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLUTION:

I forgot to update the scopes to my appsettings.Development.json

All my scopes were properly listed, but they were only in my appsettings.json file, and not in the appsettings.Development.json